# Having trouble accessing the rest of the row with MySQL MAX function

Tags: mysql, max

Im trying to return a different column on the row returned with the MAX function. For instance I have a table with eggs => 10 and bacon => 20. I'm trying to return eggs or bacon based on the value. I've tried this:

```
SELECT column1, MAX(column2) FROM table
```

I can't seem to access the value of column1. Am I missing something with the MAX function?

Answer:

```
SELECT column1, MAX(column2) as col2 FROM table GROUP BY column1 ORDER BY col2
```

Comment: Got it to work with the order by at the end.

Comment: If you have a different, better solution then please share it. Add your own answer and explain the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You want to apply the `max()` aggregate function on a group of data:

```
SELECT column1, MAX(column2) 
FROM table
group by column1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to determine the maximum value *and* get the details pertaining to that maximum value, then there are various ways to do that:

1. Use a query calculating the maximum `column2` value as a scalar subquery to match `column2` against the result (same as [@Sebas's first suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18199197/297408)):

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM atable
   WHERE column2 = (SELECT MAX(column2) FROM atable)
   ;
   ```
2. You can also use the subquery as a derived table instead:

   ```
   SELECT t.*
   FROM atable AS t
   INNER JOIN (
     SELECT MAX(column2) AS max_column2 FROM atable
   ) AS m ON t.column2 = m.max_column2
   ;
   ```
3. You could simply sort the rows in the descending order of `column2` and return the topmost one:

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM atable
   ORDER BY column2
   LIMIT 0, 1
   ;
   ```

   Note that, unlike the first two options, this one will return one row at most, even if there are ties for the maximum value.

If it is not just one maximum value but one maximum per some grouping criterion (or criteria) that you need to handle, I believe the second option of the above would be easiest to adapt:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM atable AS t
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT grouping_criterion, MAX(column2) AS max_column2
  FROM atable
  GROUP BY grouping_criterion
) AS m ON t.grouping_column = m.grouping_column
      AND t.column2 = m.max_column2
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by using the ORDER BY function.

```
SELECT column1, MAX(column2) as col2 FROM table GROUP BY column1 ORDER BY col2
```